# Convert an R object to a List

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, rpy2

I've got a script that runs **R** from **Python**:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
binom = importr('binom')
from rpy2 import robjects

robjects.r('''library(binom)
p = seq(0,1,.001)
coverage = binom.coverage(p, 25, method="asymptotic")$coverage
''')

R_P = robjects.r['p']
R_C = robjects.r['coverage']
```

I can see the result using **plt.scatter**:

[image]

But when I try **plt.plot** I get:

```
AttributeError: 'FloatVector' object has no attribute 'find'
```

R_C is an:

```
R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
<FloatVector - Python:0x0000002CA644E448 / R:0x0000002CA14A6D38>
[1.000000, 0.024702, 0.048818, 0.072360, ..., 0.072360, 0.048818, 0.024702, 1.000000]
```

To get a **line plot** of R_C against R_P, do I need to convert it to a **list** and how do I do that please?

Comment: How are you calling `plt.plot`? When I try `plt.plot(R_C)` it works.

Comment: Interesting point @Jason, yes plt.plot(R_C) works but not plt.plot(R_P, R_C). I want to plot them against each other, like in the scatter plot please.

Comment: Maybe `plt.plot(list(R_P), list(R_C))`?

Comment: @R.Cox For some reason when I run `plt.plot(R_P, R_C)` it works on my end. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/WO9gH8i.png. It shouldn't matter that R_P and R_C are `FloatVector`s, because they implement `__getitem__` and act like sequences. Furthermore, `list`s also do not have the attribute `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JohanC, this works!

```
plt.plot(list(R_P), list(R_C))
```

or

```
R_P = list(robjects.r['p'])
R_C = list(robjects.r['coverage'])
```